# JQuery click method require double click on responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery

click method working fine on desktop but in mobile (or even responsive layout on web) require double click.

Here is the code below

```
$('body').on('click', '.share-toggle', function(){
   console.log('this', this)
   return;
});
```

Comment: For mobile devices, I would recommend using some library that can handle tap events.

Comment: Working on a legacy system and sadly we are not allowed to use any other thing/library

Comment: You could use the touchstart event maybe

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) concerning the touch events in JS

Comment: @sultanaslam was your issue fixed?

Comment: @VishnuBaliga no

Comment: @sultanaslam did u check my answer below?

Comment: tried that but same result

Answer (score 0):

You can try to trigger the function by click and touch, example:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {
```

Or this:

```
$(document).on('click touch', function () {
```

The touchstart event fires as soon as an element is touched, the `touch` event is more like a "tap", i.e. a single contact on the surface. You should really try each of these to see what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with "touchend" event.

```
$("body").delegate('.share-toggle','click touchend',function(){
    console.log('this', this)
    return;
}
```